# Востановить бекап MySQL базы

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Пытаюсь востановить дамп базы из файла.

**код:**

```
 $dbhost=$host;
 $dblogin=$user;
 $dbpass=$password;
 $dbname=$database;

 $q=file_get_contents("http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/install/dump.sql");

 //Подключаемся к серверу баз данных
    $db = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dblogin, $dbpass);
             mysql_select_db ($dbname, $db);

    if(!mysql_query($q,$db)) die('Ошибка запроса: '.mysql_error($db).'<br>');
        else echo 'Запрос успешно выполнен';
}
```

**Получаю вот такой ответ:**

> Ошибка запроса: You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near 'INSERT INTO `admin` (`login`,
> `password`) VALUES ('admin',
> '21232f297a57a5a74389' at line 14

**Вот фрагрмент базы:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `login` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

--
-- Дамп даних таблиці `admin`
--

INSERT INTO `admin` (`login`, `password`) VALUES
('admin', '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблиці `comments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_article` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `date_add` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `public` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `st` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AUTO_INCREMENT=93 ;
```

**14 строка** на котороую ругается это INSERT INTO `admin` (`login`, `password`) VALUES

Не могу понять в чем проблема, бекам был сделан на этом же хостинге по средству Експорта из myadmin

Comment: Ругань идёт не на 14 строку, а рядом с запросом. Смотрите строки выше 14.

Comment: получается ругань на создание таблицы админ, но если запрос создания просто скопировать и выполнить через панель управления, ругани никакой нету. таблица создается

Comment: mysql_* не позволяет выполнять серию запросов. попробуйте разбить на отдельные запросы или использовать mysqli_*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам не принципиально, залейте дамп через консоль. Например так:

```
cat my_dump.sql | mysql -v -u -h127.0.0.1 -p
```

**UPDATE**
читайте мануалы на оф [сайте](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php):
mysql_query() посылает один запрос (*посылка нескольких запросов не поддерживается*) активной базе данных сервера, на который ссылается переданный дескриптор link_identifier.

**UPDATE 2**
И вообще переходите на [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

Comment: или так  
mysql -u... -p -h10.10.10.10 DBName < dump.sql > log